# How to add a sector to the list of badblocks for ext4?

Tags: ext4, bad-blocks

dumpe2fs -b /dev/sdd1
can dump blocks that are known to be bad by ext4.

How do I manually add a block to that list without redoing mkfs ?

Answer (score 0):

From [`man 8 e2fsck`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/e2fsck):

> `-l filename`
>   Add the block numbers listed in the file specified by `filename` to the list of bad blocks. The format of this file is the same as the one generated by the `badblocks(8)` program. Note that the block numbers are based on the blocksize of the filesystem. Hence, `badblocks(8)` must be given the blocksize of the filesystem in order to obtain correct results. As a result, it is much simpler and safer to use the `-c` option to `e2fsck`, since it will assure that the correct parameters are passed to the `badblocks` program.
>
> `-L filename`
>   Set the bad blocks list to be the list of blocks specified by `filename`. (This option is the same as the `-l` option, except the bad blocks list is cleared before the blocks listed in the file are added to the bad blocks list.)

I've seen few output files from `badblocks` that were not empty, so I can tell the general format is simple: one decimal number per line. Numbering starts from `0` but as far as I know `e2fsck -l` won't accept `0` and will complain about few initial blocks (where some crucial filesystem metadata exist).

Example file content:

```
12345
678900
```

My tests were limited. Try the solution on a [scratch monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_monkey) first.